# error: no matching function for call to `qsort(int[((unsigned int)((int)n))])'

Tags: c++, sorting, quicksort, partition

There are two warnings on my IDE:

> **[Warning]** C:\PROGRA~2\C-FREE~1\mingw\include\stdlib.h:367: note:
>   candidates are:
>
> ```
> void qsort(void*, size_t, size_t, int (*)(const void*,const void*))
> ```

and

> **[Warning]** D:\saltpass_c\未命名7.cpp:20: note:
>
> ```
> std::allocator<int> >&)
> ```

My code:

```cpp
int par(vector<int>&arr, int low, int high)
{
    int pivot = arr[low];
    while(low < high)
    {
        while(low < high && arr[high] >= pivot)high--;
        arr[low] = arr[high];
        while(low < high && arr[low] <= pivot)low++;
        arr[high] = arr[low];
    }
    arr[low] = pivot;
    return low;
}
int qsort(vector<int>&arr)
{
     int mystack[2000];
     int top = -1;
     mystack[++top] = 0;
     mystack[++top] = arr.size() - 1;
     while(top > 0)
     {
         int high = mystack[top--], low = mystack[top--];
         int middle = par(arr, low, high);
         if(middle+1 < high)
         {
             mystack[++top] = middle+1;
             mystack[++top] = high;
         }
         if(low < middle-1)
         {
             mystack[++top] = low;
             mystack[++top] = middle-1;
         }
     }
 }
```

**Why are those warnings appearing and how can I get rid of them?**

Comment: What does `未命名7` mean?

Comment: I'm guessing you have `using namespace std;` in your code, right? Remove that or rename your `qsort` function to not conflict with the one you get from `<cstdint>`.

Comment: @LogicalBranch it means `Untitled 7`